# PROCESSING: get pixel value of a gray scale image

Tags: image, image-processing, processing, rgb, grayscale

```
grayValue = (int)((gray.pixels[locGray]))  ;
```

the grayvalue should be positive any help?

Comment: and what's the problem?

Comment: do you mean as a positive number ? it's might be just the way the colour's represented as an int...print the hex() or brightness() of the that pixel if you're not sure

Answer (score 0):

Is locGray in range for the array?  You could be reading a random value from memory if you are out of range, and this is c/c++